# Assertion fails after passing HWND to DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, mfc

In our application, we have specialized modules in DLLs, which get control over a window inside our main application window. We pass the window as `HWND`, not as a `CWnd*`. Inside the DLL, I use `CWnd::FromHandle` to get a CWnd*, which I use as a parent to create a `CHtmlView` inside that window.

As soon as this view is about to be shown, a debug assertion occurs in `wincore.cpp`:

```
    if(pMap)
    {
        ASSERT( (p = pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd)) != NULL ||
                (p = pMap->LookupTemporary(m_hWnd)) != NULL);
    }
    ASSERT((CWnd*)p == this);   // must be us

    // Note: if either of the above asserts fire and you are
    // writing a multithreaded application, it is likely that
    // you have passed a C++ object from one thread to another
    // and have used that object in a way that was not intended.
    // (only simple inline wrapper functions should be used)
    //
    // In general, CWnd objects should be passed by HWND from
    // one thread to another.  The receiving thread can wrap
    // the HWND with a CWnd object by using CWnd::FromHandle.
    //
    // It is dangerous to pass C++ objects from one thread to
    // another, unless the objects are designed to be used in
    // such a manner.
```

Here the line with LookupTemporary fails, altough I used it exactly as described in the comment. In release mode, or if I just place an empty `AssertValid`-method in my view class, everything works fine.

My question: how can this happen, and is it something I should care about?

Comment: Are you creating the CHtmlView in a different thread from the main application thread? Parent and child windows being in different threads will not work.

Comment: How are `p` and `m_hWnd` assigned?

Comment: The dll must be an **MFC Extension Dll** for this to work, otherwise each dll has its own static instance of MFCs internal window maps, and a window in one module will not appear in the map of another module.

Comment: The view is created inside the DLL, but not explicitly in another thread. I don't know if the MFC internally creates a thread for each view. But it works fine, it's just the assertion I'm wondering about.

Comment: @user1793036: I think this might be the right answer. Do you have any documentation about that? MSDN link?

Comment: If you need to do any of the above or need to pass MFC-derived objects between the calling executable and the DLL, you must build an extension DLL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea%28v=VS.80%29.aspx